# Draw figures with turtle

Tags: python-2.7, methods, turtle-graphics

I am looking to draw some figures with Python 2.7 using the turtle module. I have tried to write several functions, but each time I am running the programm (I am using pycharm), it runs without problem, but doesn't draw anything.

I am sure it's something not so difficult, but somehow I keep missing it.

The last one I typed was this one:

```
 import turtle
    speed(11)
    def triangle(cote):
        down()
        for i in range(3):
            forward(cote)
            left(120)
        up()
    def sierpinski(cote):
        if (cote>16):
            for i in range(3):
                sierpinski(cote/2)
                forward(cote)
                left(120)
            else:
                 triangle(cote)
    up()
    back(256)
    sierpinski(512)
    done()
```

and a previous one, this one:

```
    import turtle

def triangle(longueur):
    for i in range(3):
        forward(longueur)
        left(120)
```

I assume, I am not calling the method well, but, I tried `triangle`, `triangle()`, `triangle(19)`. None worked.

Comment: Is this exactly how your code looks on your machine? Ex. `import turtle` has no indentation, and `speed(11)` has four spaces of indentation? If so, I'm surprised the script is running at all.

Comment: If I change your imports to `from turtle import *` (so you can use turtle's functions as you do without using `turtle.` prefix) and fix your indentations the sierpinski triangle is correctly drawn on my machine. In fact I wonder that your code runs at all just with `import turtle` and **not** adding `turtle.` to your turtle function calls.

Comment: Somehow, this website added the indents, none were into the actual code.
I managed to make it draw. However, the Sierpinski triangle draw himself and stay there, the window of the other one juste shut down, after the drawing and I do not see what could make it act as such, the done() ?